# duplicate fields in different divs

Tags: angular

I have a button, that its functionality is to duplicate the bottom inputs, but they have to be duplicated in 2 different divs, that is, first click on the button, it renders a new field in div 1, the second click, renders in div 2, the third click, renders again in div 1, and so on.

I'm doing it as follows:

```
  duplicateFields() {
    let currentDiv = document.getElementById('duplicate');
    let clonedDiv = currentDiv.cloneNode(true);
    currentDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(clonedDiv, currentDiv.nextSibling);
  }
```

DIV 1

```
<div fxLayout="row" class="row-qtd-ingredients" id="duplicate">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100%">
      <input matInput placeholder="Qtde">
      <mat-hint fxHide>Hint</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100%" class="m-l-10">
      <input matInput placeholder="Ingredientes">
      <mat-hint fxHide>Hint</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

DIV 2

```
 <div fxLayout="row" class="row-qtd-ingredients">
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100%" ngClass.gt-sm="m-l-10">
       <input matInput placeholder="Qtde">
       <mat-hint fxHide>Hint</mat-hint>
     </mat-form-field>
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100%" class="m-l-10">
       <input matInput placeholder="Ingredientes">
       <mat-hint fxHide>Hint</mat-hint>
     </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

However, he only duplicates it on div 1, he wanted it to be merged between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have in your HTML something like this:

```
<div id="duplicate"...>...</div>
<div...>...</div>
```

and not something like this:

```
<div id="duplicate"...>...</div><div...>...</div>
```

Note in the second markup there is no space between the two divs. If I am correct on first click getting the `nextSibling` should return `#text` ([nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)). So what you actually have as DOM is this:

```
<div id="duplicate"...>...</div>
#text
<div...>...</div>
```

On first click you are cloning the `duplicate` and insert it before its firs sibling so you will end with DOM like this:

```
<div id="duplicate"...>...</div>
<div id="first-clone"...>...</div>
#text
<div...>...</div>
```

At this point the `firsSibling` of `duplicate` div is the first clone. Therefore on second click you will insert the second clone between the duplicate and first clone. The DOM will look like this:

```
<div id="duplicate"...>...</div>
<div id="second-clone"...>...</div>
<div id="first-clone"...>...</div>
#text
<div...>...</div>
```

On so on on each next click the clone will go after the duplicate and before the previous clone.

What you can do is get `nextElementSibling` and not `nextSibling`. Keep in mind `nextElementSibling` is not fully supported in some browsers.